# Automatic email without loading the page using ajax,php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am facing an error in ajax while running the code. The control is not going inside the ajax. If condition is not true.

Below is the code I am using.

I am getting values through php in JavaScript.

```js
var days = "<?php echo $days; ?>";
alert(days);
var flag = "<?php echo $flag; ?>";
alert(flag);
$.ajax({
      url: (days == 18 && flag == 0) ? "email_reminder.php" : "reminder.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        //PROBLEM HERE **********
        if (data.success == 'true') {
          alert('true');
        } else {
          alert('false')
        };
      });
```

Comment: Open your devtools (if on chrome, press F12) and go to network tab. See what happens when you run this request.

Comment: Maybe Status Code `500`?

Comment: put console.log(data); before your if condition and check what it is returning, may be you are comparing string and its returning boolean true or false

Comment: @Purushottamzende will not be logged due to the `if...else` condition is also not working

Comment: add an error function as you did for success:

Comment: @messerbill, no i mean , put it in success or as suggested by , use error function, just put it before if condtion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is this:

```
dataType: "html",
success: function (data) {
    //PROBLEM HERE **********
    if(data.success == 'true' ){
```

You set the dataType to `html` but then you treat it as if it is `json`. You need to parse it manually or set the dataType to `json` so that jQuery does that automatically:

```
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    //PROBLEM HERE **********
    if(data.success == 'true' ){
```

If there are other problems, you need to check the Network tab of the browser's developer tools to see what the exact response is.